# How to access ScrollViewer in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, scrollviewer

I'm trying to access the ScrollViewer named 'ScrollViewerItems' in the XAML below and use it in code behind. The name doesn't seem to be recognized, likely because its embedded in the ItemsControl. I don't need the named access, but how to I get to the ItemsControl's ScrollViewer in code behind?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="EnteredItemsView" ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}"  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerItems" Focusable="False">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    ...
```

Comment: you can use visual tree helper or can or query on templatedchild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ScrollViewer is the visual child of the ItemsControl:

```
var scrollViewer =
    VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(EnteredItemsView, 0) as ScrollViewer;
```

---

Note that the ItemsControl must have been loaded before you can access the child.

You may add a `Loaded` handler to the ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl Loaded="ItemsControlLoaded" ...>
```

where you access the ScrollViewer

```
private void ItemsControlLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var itemsControl = sender as DependencyObject;
    var scrollViewer =
        VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itemsControl, 0) as ScrollViewer;
}
```

Comment: Specified index is out of range or child at index is null. Do not call this method if VisualChildrenCount returns zero, indicating that the Visual has no children. EnteredItemsView.VisualChildrenCount was 0 FYI

Comment: You called GetChild before the ItemsControl was loaded! See my edit.